# Visual Studio project not working in Blend (reference errors)

Tags: xaml, reference, expression-blend, blend, mahapps.metro

When I open my project that uses a `MahApps.Metro` window in "Blend for Visual Studio" I get tons of errors. One of them is (this one probably causes all the other errors):

```
The name "MetroWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

This same project works fine in Visual Studio 2012. Additionally, all resources in Blend have a warning icon. How could I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've not have a chance to test out the new "Blend for Visual Studio 2012" release but I'll see if I can recreate it locally. Captured here:  https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. I changed the debug platform on all the projects in my solution to `Any CPU` like this:

1. Opened the project in both Visual Studio and Blend
2. Opened the `Configuration Manager` (drop down menu beside debug/release "Start" button)
3. One of the projects' debug platform was set to `x86` so I clicked on `<new...>`
4. Set `New Platform` to `Any CPU`
5. Set `Copy Settings From` to `<Empty>`
6. Clicked `Ok`
7. Blend then asked me to reload the project and I clicked on `Yes To All`